# The google map looks empty inside the simulator

Tags: android, dictionary

```
public class Map extends MapActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myMapView1);

            mapView.getController().animateTo(srcGeoPoint);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(15);

}
```

the map.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  > 
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
android:id="@+id/myMapView1" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_x="0px" 
  android:enabled="true" 
  android:clickable="true" 
 android:apiKey="Obtained Key here" android:layout_y="105px"             android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
  </com.google.android.maps.MapView> 
 </LinearLayout>
```

I check the log there's only one red mark, Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings. everything else seems to be fine.  I am wondering why the map is empty looking?

Comment: Are you running it on a Google API emulator?

Comment: Is it safe to post the api key free? Just questioning.

Comment: You might want to take that down. :/

Answer (score 4):

The MapView is empty when your Maps API key is expired or not matching with your debug signature key.
Try to generate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

> Inside every MapActivity, the isRouteDisplayed() method is required,
>   so override this method:
>
> @Override protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
>       return false; }
>
> This method is required for some accounting from the Maps service to
>   see if you're currently displaying any route information. In this
>   case, you're not, so return false.
>
> source: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Additional the `android:layout_x="0px` looks a little bit dodgy to me. I think it's only used in AbsoluteLayouts so deleting it should not harm.

Answer (score 0):

Please check logs whether you are not getting "unable to authenticate error from google server". If yes there is issue with map key.
**Map key should be generate on same system where you are running application.**
Also check whether you have google play account signed and location setting is enabled.

please check here for more details:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start